# Calling a mysql method

Tags: php, mysql

I want to execute the method showResultsDB() 2 times,but ive got only one time executed. Why the second times doesnt work?

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/qq9-i4v

```
<?php
/**EXAMPLE________DB**/
$db = new DBConnection('localhost', 'root', '', 'webshop', 'galleries');

// echo $ddb->hostname;

$db->startConnectionDB();
$res = $db->queryDB();
$res1 = $db->queryDB();
$db->showResultsDB($res, MYSQL_ASSOC); //MYSQL_BOTH or MYSQL_ROW
$db->showResultsDB($res, MYSQL_ASSOC); //MYSQL_BOTH or MYSQL_ROW




?>
```

Comment: Do a `queryDB` immediately followed by a `showResultsDB`

Comment: Do you mean to call it twice with `$res`? There's no way to answer without seeing the code for `showResultsDB`, but I'd assume it moves the pointer of the resultset to the end, so the second call doesn't have any records to display.

Comment: Since you're declaring `$res1` as a new variable, I take it you want `$db->showResultsDB($res1, MYSQL_ASSOC); //MYSQL_BOTH or MYSQL_ROW` ?

Comment: Why, oh why, do you want to call it twice?

Comment: This may be related to data seek, you need to reset the result pointer.

Comment: What a nice example of XY problem. Instead of focusing how to describe the end goal, you have an idea that you *think* will solve it and you got stuck while trying to make it work. To give you the proper answer - you don't call the method twice. You save the output to a variable. Once. And you pass the variable with data to your function. Not the query resource. And your problem goes away, as if it was never there.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Sorry for not being clear. I know that i could call showResults method with res1, i just don t understand why do i need to create another variable in order to use this method ;)

Comment: @Olegalex - you don't need to, really. There's a pointer included in the recordset, and when you call the function for the first time, the pointer steps through the recordset and the function ends when there are no more records to be returned. When you call the function for a second time, the pointer is already at the end of the recordset, so it looks like there are no records to return.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $res1 in the second line instead of $res, no ?

```
$db->showResultsDB($res, MYSQL_ASSOC); //MYSQL_BOTH or MYSQL_ROW
$db->showResultsDB($res1, MYSQL_ASSOC); //MYSQL_BOTH or MYSQL_ROW
```